# Query regarding pointers in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, binary-search-tree

I am trying to access the root node of a BST from within a function. Can I do it without passing a pointer to the root node in the function parameters?

```
 bool insert(int item)
     {
        BstNode *parent;
        BstNode *ptr;
        BstNode *root;
```

Comment: You should be clear about what you're trying to do, instead of naming one thing that you don't want to do.  The answer to this question is "Yes".

Answer (score -2):

You could:

- pass a pointer to the root node as a function parameter (or a pointer or reference to such a pointer if you think you may need to modify it)
- pass a pointer to some structure containing a pointer to the root node
- put the pointer to the root node into a class and make `insert` a member function so it can access the pointer
- read the pointer from some global / namespace / static location (not recommended)